# A lower bound on $B$-smooth numbers less then $x$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I want an estimate of the number of B-smooth numbers less than or equal to $x$. Let it be denoted by $\Psi(x,B)$.

It is well known that, $$\Psi(x,B) \sim \frac{1}{\pi(B)!}\prod_{p\leq x}\frac{\log x}{\log p}$$

However, I am interested in a strict lower bound, without assuming any unproven hypothesis (such as GRH).

Assume $x > B^2$, it is easy to prove that  $\Psi(x,B) > B^2$. Can we improve this bound?

Comment: A bad lower bound is $\pi(B)^{\frac{\ln x}{\ln B}}$, but sure we make sure that the number of $B-smooth$ number less than $x$ will be bigger than $B^k$ if $x >B^k$ for any $k\geq 1$.